# Netlify error on build image Xenial Xerus deprecated

Tags: next.js, build, netlify, github-cli

Build image deploy error

[Disclaimer: I'm a beginner on deployment of apps]
Hi there,
I tried to deploy my web page (Nextjs) on Netlify and I'm getting a weird error on github CLI. When I see the logs of failed CLI tests it says:
"
UNSUPPORTED BUILD IMAGE
The build image for this site uses Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus, which is no longer supported.
".

I checked the settings and I'm not using this deprecated image. Anyone had the same issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ?found any solution